# Identify coordinate system point

Tags: wkt, epsg

I need to find the "normal" latitude and longitude of a point in this format:

POINT (-8114244 4999772)

I tried using DBGeography.CreateFromPoint, but i think i used the wrong srid.

(i have searched before asking the question, but being numbers google is not very helpful).

Thank you

Comment: You have tagged this as c#? Just wanted to make sure you did not forget to post code or something. Because right now it seems this has nothing to do with c# as I can see.

Comment: yes, you are right, i've taken the tag down

Comment: Are you sure that the format you posted is correct?

I dont know how EPSG works at all, but assuming the values are weird and not in their typical range you might have a type issue. Where does the values -8114244 and 4999772 come from? Sure your input is not in format A and you have casted it to format B?

Comment: it's from this:

http://www.longislandindexmaps.org/

{"id":429,"name":null,"address":"10 Wooleys La.","city":"Great Neck","decadeBlt":0,"totalUnits":12,"propertyType":null,"yearBlt":0,"expectedCompletion":0,"downtownArea":null,"aptConversion":0,"detailedInfo":null,"wkt":"POINT (-8207941 4982429)"}